# How to fix lag on select element containing a large list of options

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I have a react application that uses react material ui, i am using the autocomplete `react-select` example which you can find here.

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

When the number of items in the select is large for example around 2500~ it lags and becomes unusable.

I have modified the original demo to make suggestions of length 2500 to populate the select.

```
const suggestions = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 2500; i = i + 1) {
  suggestions.push({ value: i, label: `Option ${i}` });
}
```

Please see the below demo example of my problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-vp59j

When you click the first selector it is very laggy.

Comment: you can always use the idea of infinite scroll. Load certain number of data at first and load slowly as user scroll through.

Comment: There are some suggestions here that might be helpful: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3128

Answer (score 21):

I used "filterOptions" to show first 500 items and other items still be matched when searched, like this.

```
  import Autocomplete, { createFilterOptions } from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

  const filterOptions = createFilterOptions({
    matchFrom: 'any',
    limit: 500,
  });
  
  <Autocomplete
    filterOptions={filterOptions}
  />
```

For more arguments. >> https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#custom-filter

Comment: Ohh Man! You saved my days! Have been struggling with this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: that's awesome dude

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue as I had to create a drop-down for around 3000 values.
The trick is to show a limited items in the Autocomplete drop-down and let users search ones that cannot be found in the drop-down.

Use Filteroptions feature of material Ui Autocomplete and use a limit param and set it to say 200.

Autocomplete will show only 200 items in the drop-down and rest can be searched.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `react-window` for this purpose. https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window

It is a library for efficiently rendering large lists and tabular data.

Here is a working demo with a lot records to show. It doesn't lag https://codesandbox.io/s/bvaughnreact-window-fixed-size-list-vertical-bbtz0

P.S: It is by one of the core guys on facebook react team.

Comment: i need a solution with the current libraries im using material ui and react-select

Comment: There is an example of material-ui with react-virtialized https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#virtualized-list

Comment: That example actually does use `react-window` and not `react-virtualized`.

Comment: react-window is like the updated version of react-virtualized by the same author.

Comment: @AdeelImran But What about the dropdown like behavior. This is just a list and doesn't have a similar behavior. Also what if we want the multiple select items using this virtualized list.

Comment: As @dev_khan says, this is just a list, not a select at all :/

Comment: This is the Solution is was looking for. https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#custom-filter has a nice solution and a codepen. Currently I am loading a 30K data set and it's doing a great job.